# Parse XML response in javascript. get value of specific tag in javascript

Tags: javascript, parsing, xml-parsing

I have xml response. I want to get the value of "respuesta" in `<return>` tag.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://">
    <S:Body>
        <ns2:cardtransactionResponse xmlns:ns2="http://">
            <return>
                {
                 "terminalid":"00250425",
                 "retailerid":"000000001848033",
                 "trantime":"151333",
                 "referencia":"021515133324",
                 "networkid":"024",
                 "respuesta":"00",
                 "trandate":"0802",
                 "tipomensaje":"000000",
                 "auditno":"000016"
                 }
            </return>
        </ns2:cardtransactionResponse>
    </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

Comment: You are asking about parsing XML in JavaScript. I don't see how this has anything to with HTML or PHP, so I removed those tags from your question. Please add only relevant tags to your question next time.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to parse this json using a regex approach, you can try the following:

```
const responsemsg = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://">
<S:Body>
    <ns2:cardtransactionResponse xmlns:ns2="http://">
        <return>
            {
             "terminalid":"00250425",
             "retailerid":"000000001848033",
             "trantime":"151333",
             "referencia":"021515133324",
             "networkid":"024",
             "respuesta":"00",
             "trandate":"0802",
             "tipomensaje":"000000",
             "auditno":"000016"
             }
        </return>
    </ns2:cardtransactionResponse>
</S:Body>
</S:Envelope>`
const regexexp = /\"respuesta\"\:(.+?)\,/
const respuestaMatch = regexexp.exec(responsemsg);
console.log(respuestaMatch[0])
//""respuesta":"00","
console.log(respuestaMatch[1])
//"00"
```

If you would like to learn more about regex, [follow link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp).

Answer (score 0):

Since you're dealing with xml, the best way to approach it is using xpath:

```
const xmlstring = `[your xml above]`
let DOMParser = require('xmldom').DOMParser,
  doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(xmlstring),
  xpath = require('xpath'), 
  select = xpath.useNamespaces({ns2: 'ns2'}),
  target = select('//return', doc, true);
console.log(target.toString().split( '"respuesta":')[1].split( ',')[0]);
```

Output:

```
"00"
```